# Unselect all checkboxes inside a specific div except the one checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my div

```
<div id="extras">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="extra-Material">
        <div class="form-group"><label>Material</label>
            <br
            ><label class="checkbox-inline mr10">
                <input name="ffp[]" type="checkbox" value="1_1"> Fabric</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline mr10"><input name="ffp[]" type="checkbox" value="1_2"> Wood</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="extra-Color">
        <div class="form-group"><label>Color</label><br><label class="checkbox-inline mr10"><input name="ffp[]"
                                                                                                   type="checkbox"
                                                                                                   value="2_8">
                Brown</label><label class="checkbox-inline mr10"><input name="ffp[]" type="checkbox" value="2_5">
                Red</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I have 2 inner divs `extra-Material` and `extra-Color`. These are being generated dynamically basically. All these appended divs have the same checkbox name inside it `ffp[]`. I want 1 checkbox to be selected at 1 time. Lets say that I click on 'Fabric' and then on 'Wood', it should only unselect the Fabric (All the checkboxes inside 1st div with id = `extra-Material`) should be unchecked and then Wood should be checked. Similarly with second div and so on. I have searched and there is code to unselect all the checkboxes on page but I don't want that. Anyone can help me?

This is my JS Code

```
if (json_data.length > 0) {
    var html = '';
    html += '<div class="col-md-12" id="extra-' + name + '">'
    html += '<div class="form-group">';
    html += '<label>' + name + '</label>';
    html += '<br>';
    json_data.forEach(function (entry) {

        html += '<label class = "checkbox-inline mr10" >';
        html += '<input name="ffp[]" type = "checkbox" value = "' + val + '_' + entry.ffp_id + '"> ' + entry.en_name + '';
        html += '</label>';

    });
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    $('#extras').append(html);
}
```

Comment: I'd use radio button for material (as you only need one at time) and on click of the radio button, unselect all checkbox from extra-color`$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `bind` a `change` event handler to `input` **DOM** element.

Also, use `.closest()` method in order to get all input elements from the current set.

You should use `.on` method in order to bind event handlers for elements added **dynamically**.

**Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.**

Read more about event delegation 
[here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
   $(this).closest('.col-md-12').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
   $(this).prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extras">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="extra-Material">
        <div class="form-group"><label>Material</label>
            <br
            ><label class="checkbox-inline mr10">
                <input name="ffp[]" type="checkbox" value="1_1"> Fabric</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline mr10"><input name="ffp[]" type="checkbox" value="1_2"> Wood</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="extra-Color">
        <div class="form-group"><label>Color</label><br><label class="checkbox-inline mr10"><input name="ffp[]"
                                                                                                   type="checkbox"
                                                                                                   value="2_8">
                Brown</label><label class="checkbox-inline mr10"><input name="ffp[]" type="checkbox" value="2_5">
                Red</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou. But why was the code before not working?

Comment: @AliZia, you should use `on` method. `$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){` for elements added dynamically.

Comment: @AliZia, i updated my answer with a explanation for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$( "input[name='ffp[]']" ).bind( "change", function(){
    $(this).closest( ".form-group").find("input[name='ffp[]']").not($(this)).prop("checked", false);
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$( "#extras" ).on("change", "input[name='ffp[]']", function() {
  $(this).closest( ".form-group").find("input[name='ffp[]']").not($(this)).prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extras">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="extra-Material">
    <div class="form-group"><label>Material</label>
      <br><label class="checkbox-inline mr10"><input name="ffp[]" type="checkbox" value="1_1"> Fabric</label><label class="checkbox-inline mr10"><input name="ffp[]" type="checkbox" value="1_2"> Wood</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="extra-Color">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Color</label><br><label class="checkbox-inline mr10"><input name="ffp[]" type="checkbox" value="2_8"> Brown</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline mr10"><input name="ffp[]" type="checkbox" value="2_5">Red</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does it do? You need to bind this event after appending all such checkboxes to your document. Is it possible for you to share a fiddle?

Comment: @AliZia I have shared a demo as well.

Comment: These divs are being created on click. Maybe that's why?

Comment: @AliZia use the event-delegation, I have updated the code